# SpringBoot app running on AWS-EC2 unable to connect to MySQL AWS-RDS database

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-ec2, spring-boot, amazon-rds

I am having problems running an app I have developed in an EC2 instance. When I execute the .jar (java -jar app.jar), the SpringBoot app starts but it fails when trying to connect to my MySQL RDS database. The thing is when I run the app locally on my machine, It has no issues with the DB connection.

I have opened the port where the app is running (8090) and MySql port as well (3306) for inbound and outbound traffic:

[image]

This is the error I get:

```html
2016-09-23 17:46:38.132  INFO 10161 --- [main] .t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory : Server initialized with port: 8090
2016-09-23 17:46:38.604  INFO 10161 --- [main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-09-23 17:46:38.605  INFO 10161 --- [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
2016-09-23 17:46:38.724  INFO 10161 --- [ost startStop 1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-09-23 17:46:38.725  INFO 10161 --- [ost startStop 1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 5028 ms
2016-09-23 17:48:48.476 ERROR 10161 --- [ost startStop 1] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool: Unable to create initial connections of pool.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

Any ideas how can i solve this problem?

Thank you very much  for your help

Regards

Andres

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your description and log file, it's likely that network configuration is the cause here.

You might want to draw the network topology of your instances (region/availability zone, VPC, subnet, network acl, security group). This will be very helpful when you do more complex development work.
There are good references: [VPC Introduction](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Introduction.html) and [Security in your VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Security.html) and [Scenarios for Accessing a DB Instance in a VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html)

I suggest the following actions for your troubleshooting:

- Check security group (SG) configuration of your EC2 instance and RDS instance.
  You can check this by going to EC2 Dashboard/RDS Dashboard -> Click on an instance and look at "Security Group" description, or you can click on the Setting icon (Show/Hide columns) and tick "Security Groups".

  In RDS's SG configuration: make sure you have enable access from EC2 instance's SG to port 3306. You can do this by putting EC2 instance's SG ID into Source field of the config, as a "Custom IP" value. See the 1st scenario in the above reference for more detail.
- Use mysql command line to test the connection between EC2 instance and RDS.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for you response @LiemPham. You were right. the problem was that RDS security group did no have an Inbound Rule for EC2 security group. Both RDS and EC2 were in the same VPC and subnet but they could not talk to each other. The three link related to VPC were very useful to understand how EC2 and RDS communicates in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform following steps :

1) Go to EC2 instance and find security group you want access in RDS

[image]

2) Now go to your RDS security group and select inbound rules
  Select ALL TCP and add your sg-xxx(security group)

[image]

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html